# Is there an expression in "il ne s'y est pas pris assez tôt"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques

> Le gouvernement vénézuélien a décidé de ne pas embaumer le corps du
>   président décédé Hugo Chávez, **car il ne s'y est pas pris assez
>   tôt**.

I can't understand what it means. I don't know the grammatical components, if any, in this part of the quotation, either. I want to understand it logically; not just a translation that is basically useless without a grammatical explanation of this structure (for further reproduction in speech).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*S'y prendre* is an idiomatic expression. See item *3ème section, III* of the [TLFi definition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prendre)

> III. − **S'y prendre** .Agir d'une certaine manière en vue d'obtenir un résultat déterminé. Synon. *s'arranger*, *procéder*, *se débrouiller*.

So it basically means *to start to act*.

*S'y prendre assez tôt* thus means *to start to act soon enough*. Combined with the negative and compound past, you get that *[the government] was too late in starting the embalming work*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Très informatif. So _il_ in the _car il ne s'y est pas pris_ is _le gouvernement_, isn't it?

Comment: @indoxica Excatly

Comment: And _il ne s'y est pas pris_, according to the TLFi definition, can basically be replaced by either _il n'a pas procédé_ or _il ne s'est pas arrangé_?

Comment: *procéder* is not a good replacement here, *arranger* is a bit better. You could also use *il n'a pas engagé/initié la procédure assez tôt*.